# Conversion from PNG to EPS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, image-conversion, png

I would like to convert PNG images/graphs to EPS without losing even a bit on resolution. All the things I tried (potrace, autotrace, using convert, gimp) the resolution is getting too bad. Any kind of help will be highly appreciated. I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: Related: [PNG to eps conversion massive increase in file size](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4408813/2533433), and the article [Convert png to eps](http://linuxtricksandtips.blogspot.de/2011/12/convert-png-to-eps.html), which mentions a software named "bmeps" as the solution for high-res conversion. Not tried it myself, but thought mentioning it might be helpful.

Comment: I'm actually using Inkscape for bitmap vectorization. I don't know if you can directly output EPS, but i'm pretty sure converting SVG to EPS is very easily and totally lossless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vector Magic](http://vectormagic.com/home) is the best image to vector program in my humble opinion.

Here is an example jpg that I have vectorized in the following image using Vector Magic:

[image: panofish logo]

Here is a zoomed area of the resultant vector.  Vector Magic give great flexibility to choose the number of colors and the degree of vectorization.  In this example I chose 3 main colors, black, white and brown.  Vector Magic detected and suggested those colors, but I could have chosen more or fewer.  You can also choose the degree of vector detail.  This example took me less than a minute to generate and I can regenerate on the fly... until I am happy with the result.

[image: panofish vector]

If you have a high quality bitmap for input you will quickly get a high quality vector with little need to tweak in illustrator (or your favorite vector package).  But, even with a low resolution and image with compression artifacts, Vector Magic can detect the artifacts and provide a quality vector which may need some revision in illustrator.  This will still be faster than creating the vector from scratch.

Features:

- Batchable
- Full automation, Basic or Advanced with fine-tuned control.
- Palette selection
- Anti-aliasing engine
- Artifact rejection
- Vector editing tools
- Sharp corner detection
- Path smoothing
- Background removal options

Export to EPS, SVG, PDF, AI, DXF and EMF. Works with Illustrator, Corel, and others.

This page on their site show a good comparison against alternative vectorization packages... http://vectormagic.com/home/comparisons

The software is free to try.  You can't save the vector until you buy it.  Test it with any bitmap and see for yourself

Comment: details are always nice ;)

Comment: @panofish could you expand on your answer a bit? Currently its a link only answer. Could you add a screenshot and a bit of personal experience with that tool?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) from the [ImageMagic](http://www.imagemagick.org/) package.

```
convert Image.png Image.eps
```

To install ImageMagic in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

---

You can also use **[sam2p](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/sam2p.1.html)**

It’s a small application that converts raster images into bunch of different formats. You probably won’t find it in a default installation so just do:

```
sudo apt-get install sam2p
```

Note that you need to have **universe** enabled in your apt sources. Once you install it, the rest is easy:

```
sam2p Image.png EPS: Image.eps
```